# Can't verify SHA256 fingerprint using apksigner

Tags: apk, developer-options

Just wondering if anyone can help me with the apksigner command line tool. I have just installed 'android-sdk-build-tools r30.0.3-4' on my linux machine and have subsequently tried to run the command 'apksigner verify <appname.apk>' as demonstrated on the following page, under the examples section, https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner#usage-verify.

However, when doing so, I get the following output:

/usr/bin/apksigner: line 97: exec: java: not found

Am I missing a specific java package or something? I already have js78 and nodejs installed and updated.

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: apksigner requires an installed Java runtime. What you have is JavaScript. Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster. Therefore you need to install a recent Java Runtime (e.g. openjdk-jre-8 or openjdk-jre-11)